# How to upload an uploaded file from front-end to server and then to another server

Tags: node.js

I need to upload a file from a html form in the front-end to my nodejs server, and after that PUT the same file from the nodejs server to a remote server [https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/${gArray.bucketKey}/objects/${gArray.fileName}](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/$%7BgArray.bucketKey%7D/objects/$%7BgArray.fileName%7D)

```
Step.1 {File in webpage}     ---UPLOAD[POST]--> {My node server temp}
Step.2 {File in server temp} ---UPLOAD[PUT] --> {Another remote server}
```

I don't want to store the file on my server, I want to upload it immediately to another remote server as `octet-stream`.

For doing that, at first, I upload the file from the front-end to my server:

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
    if (!files || !files.file) {
        return;
    }
    uploadToOtherServer(files.file).then(.....);
}
```

The above code works and the file is uploaded to the nodejs server. What I'm trying to do after that is to send the uploaded file to a remote server as octet-stream.

```
function uploadToOtherServer(file){
    const API_USERS_URL = `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/${gArray.bucketKey}/objects/${gArray.fileName}`;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + gArray.access_token
        };
        const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync(file.path);
        console.log('>file.path', file.path);//prints the file path on the server

        let req = http.request({
            method: 'PUT',
            uri: API_USERS_URL,
            headers: headers,
            json: true,
            body: imageBuffer
        }, (error, res, body) => {
            if (error) {
                reject('ERR_REQUEST_GEOMETRY_FILE_NOT_UPLOADED');
            } else {
                resolve(body);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

My problem is in the second code, it's not uploading the file and not showing any error in the console.

How can I upload the (file that's uploaded from the webpage to my server) to another server as `application/octet-stream`? What am I missing in my code?

Comment: If you want your file to be passed immediately to another server, then it's a perfect use-case for streams. Just pipe the incoming request stream to the new request (to another server). That should be the easiest and the best way to achieve that

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I don't think I can do that, because when I receive the file from the webpage I receive it from a `form-data`(Key, value), but when I send it, it must be sent as `octet-stream`, ie. binary/buffer .